# Locating the maximum values of a raster intersection with a vector of polygons using Python

Tags: python, raster, vector, zonal-statistics

I have extracted the statistics of a raster in the polygons of a vector layer using the python `zonal_stats` function. I need to identify the coordinates of the found maximum values. How can I do it using Python?

This is the Python script which I used to extract zonal statistics. I need to retrieve the location of `'preci_max'` for each polygon.

```
import json
import numpy as np
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

def max_round(x):
    m = x.max()
    if m is np.ma.masked:
        return None
    else:
        return m

vectorbac = "bacini.json"
raster = "preci.nc"

stats = zonal_stats(
    vectorbac, raster,
    copy_properties=True, geojson_out=True, prefix="preci_",
    stats=["count"], add_stats={
        "max": max_round,
   }
)


loopy=range(0,len(stats))
for i in loopy:
    print(stats[i]['properties']['NAME'],stats[i]['properties']['preci_max'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The **rasterstats** python module is based in **rasterio**, however, it has **crop = True** option activated by default (when I use **raster_out = True** for getting all unmasked array values) and I couldn't find an easy way for accessing to raster indices for converting them as points in map units. So, I used directly **rasterio** tools in following script (combined with your code lines for comparison purpose) and it was possible to identify the coordinates of the found maximum values.

```
import fiona
import json
import numpy as np
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask
from shapely.geometry import box, Polygon
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

def max_round(x):
    m = x.max()
    if m is np.ma.masked:
        return None
    else:
        return m

vectorbac = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon9.shp"
raster = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/raster3.tif"

stats = zonal_stats(vectorbac, 
                    raster,
                    copy_properties = True, 
                    geojson_out = True, 
                    prefix = "preci_",
                    stats = ['max'],
                    raster_out = True, 
                    add_stats = {"max": max_round})

loopy = range(0, len(stats))

geom = []

for i in loopy:
    print(stats[i]['properties']['id'], 
          stats[i]['properties']['preci_max'])
    geom.append(stats[i]['geometry']['coordinates'])

with fiona.open("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon9.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

with rasterio.open("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/raster3.tif") as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, 
                                                  shapes, 
                                                  crop = False, 
                                                  nodata = -999 )
    out_meta = src.meta

xminR = out_transform[2]
xmaxR = xminR + out_meta['width']*out_transform[0]
ymaxR = out_transform[5]
yminR = ymaxR + out_meta['height']*out_transform[4]

for i in range(len(geom)):
    poly = Polygon(geom[i][0])
    bounds = poly.bounds
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = bounds
    rowR1 = int((ymaxR - ymax)/(-out_transform[4]))
    colR1 = int((xmin - xminR)/out_transform[0])
    rowR2 = int((ymaxR - ymin)/(-out_transform[4]))
    colR2 = int((xmax - xminR)/out_transform[0])
    width = colR2 - colR1 + 1
    height = rowR2 - rowR1 + 1

    print(rowR1, colR1, rowR2, colR2, width, height)

    values = []
    indices = []

    for i in range(rowR1, rowR2):
        for j in range(colR1, colR2):
            values.append(out_image[0][i][j])
            indices.append([i,j])

    ma = np.ma.masked_equal(values, -999, copy=False)

    print(ma.max())
    idx = ma.argmax()
    print(indices[idx])
    print(xminR + indices[idx][1]*out_transform[0] + out_transform[0]/2, ymaxR + indices[idx][0]*out_transform[4] + out_transform[4]/2)
```

After running above script with layers of following image:

[image]

it was printed in Python Console following values:

```
0 2097  #first maximum with rasterstats
1 2000  #second maximum with rasterstats
2 2004  #third maximum with rasterstats
2 2 9 13 12 8
2097  #first maximum with rasterio
[3, 3] #indices for first max
457704.6911268293 4455264.170870967  #first point with rasterio
0 22 8 35 14 9
2000 #second maximum with rasterio
[4, 22] #indices for second max
459110.47684390243 4455190.182148387  #second point with rasterio
12 15 24 32 18 13
2004 #third maximum with rasterio
[19, 16]  #indices for third max
458666.54451219516 4454080.351309677  #third point with rasterio
```

With the help of **QuickWKT** plugin in QGIS 3, I generated point layers observed in above image and with **Value Tool** plugin it was corroborated that all points are effectively maximum points.

**Editing Note:**

I spent a lot of time checking each masked arrays produced with **raster_out = True** option of **rasterstats** python module and, despite it produces correct maximum values and indices, they are in a wrong position in masked arrays. So, it is impossible to identify the exact coordinates of the found maximum values with **rasterstats** module. I think that there is probably a bug in it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have inserted the masking operation into a loop on the polygons so I was able to find the maximum in each polygon. Otherwise not all the maximum values were correctly positioned. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 2):

`rasterstats.zonal_stats()` also returns affine transformation (`mini_raster_affine`) of each masked array (`mini_raster_array`), thus enabling us to locate XY position of the maximum values.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

vectorbac = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon9.shp"
raster = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/raster3.tif"

def pixel2coord(col, row):
    """Returns global coordinates to pixel center using base-0 raster index"""
    xp = a * col + b * row + a * 0.5 + b * 0.5 + c
    yp = d * col + e * row + d * 0.5 + e * 0.5 + f
    return(xp, yp)

stats = zonal_stats(vectorbac, raster , stats = ['max'], raster_out = True, geojson_out = True, nodata=-999)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('XY'))
for idx, i in enumerate(range(0, len(stats))):
    arr = stats[i]['properties']['mini_raster_array']
    col = np.argmax(np.max(arr, axis=0))
    row = np.argmax(np.max(arr, axis=1))
    c, a, b, f, d, e = stats[i]['properties']['mini_raster_affine'].to_gdal()
    df.loc[idx] = pixel2coord(col, row)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.X, df.Y))
```